# Does matrix representation being same in same basis mean linear operators are same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. Let $\{i\}=\{i_1,i_2..i_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for this space. Let $L$ and $L^{'}$ be two linear operators $L:V \to V$ and $L^{'} :  V \to V$. Now I know if these two operators are same then their matrix representation in the same basis $\{i\}$ will be the same. But is the inverse also true ? If their matrix representations are same in same basis $\{i\}$  , then the linear operators are the same ?
It might be a trivial thing but intuitively I can see that inverse statement is also true , if I am not wrong. But I am unable to prove it concretely.

Comment: Two linear transformations are equal, if and only if they map the elements of a basis in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a fixed choice of basis (for both the domain and the range spaces), a linear transformation uniquely determines and is uniquely determined by it's matrix. Infact, a linear transformation is actually the *same* as it's matrix (which is just an algebraic representation in the form of array of numbers). To see this, note that:
$$L \equiv L' \Leftrightarrow L(i_b) = \sum_{a=1}^{n} \alpha_{ab}i_a = L'(i_b) = \sum_{a=1}^{n} \beta_{ab}i_a \Leftrightarrow (\alpha_{ab}) = (\beta_{ab})$$

Here I used $a,b$ for indexing and denoting the matrix of $L$ and $L'$ by $ (\alpha_{ab})$ and $(\beta_{ab})$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the inverse statement is true.  You can reconstruct the linear map $L$ just by knowing the basis and the basis representation of $L$, so if two linear maps have the same basis representations for the same basis then you will reconstruct the same linear map for each of them.

Put another way, choosing a basis for $V$ gives a *bijection* $\hom(V, V) \simeq \mathbb M_n$ between maps $V \to V$ and matrices.  Every matrix uniquely identifies a linear map and every linear map uniquely identifies a basis.